# Does RMI Replication uses TCP or UDP for cache replication

Tags: ehcache

I am using RMI Replication in ehcache for my clustering needs.

There is a doubt here,

To replicate the cache updates(puts/updates/removes), does RMI use UDP multicast or TCP multicast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RMI uses TCP multicast to replicate the cache updates

Comment: Okay, Does it use TCP multicast to know whether any new nodes joined the cluster?

Comment: Automatic Peer Discovery

Automatic discovery uses TCP multicast to establish and maintain a multicast group. It features minimal configuration and automatic addition to and deletion of members from the group. No a priori knowledge of the servers in the cluster is required. This is recommended as the default option. Peers send heartbeats to the group once per second. If a peer has not been heard of for 5 seconds it is dropped from the group. If a new peer starts sending heartbeats it is admitted to the group.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it uses UDP, despite the [docs](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/rmi-replicated-caching.html) claiming it's TCP.
First, [TCP multicast is not possible](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16170).
Second, if you look at the code of `MulticastRMICacheManagerPeerProvider`, it uses `MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver` and `MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatSender` which both in turn use `java.net.MulticastSocket`. Here is some javadoc from that class:

> The multicast datagram socket class is useful for sending and receiving IP multicast packets. A MulticastSocket is a (UDP) DatagramSocket, with additional capabilities for joining "groups" of other multicast hosts on the internet.